# How to find X if you know Y in a line segment WPF

Tags: wpf, line, segment

I have a start point(X1,Y1) and end point(X2,Y2) I am drawing a line segment in WPF between these points , I want to calculate the value of X between this line segment if we know the Y value?

Comment: I don't understand. are X and Y points on the line joining (X1, Y1) and (X2, Y2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (x,y) is on the segment, and you know y, and y1 != y2, then

```
x = x1 + (x2-x1)*((y-y1)/(y2-y1))
```

If y1 == y2, then any x between x1 and x2 is possible, so you can't really get one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Basic high school geometry: y = mx + b, where m is the slope of the line and b is the value of y at x==0.

[This](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/slopgrph.htm) site may be of use to you.